# Laravel: Newly created log file has ownership issues

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, ownership

In my laravel project, in /storage/logs folder, there is **log file** created daily. If that **file** is created by apache then the owner and owner group becomes **www-data** and if the **file** is created by vs-code it's owner and owner group becomes **habib** (because vs-code is running under habib user)

**Here is the problem.**

-In first case when apache create that file, then it gives error if vs-code want to edit this file.

-In second case when vs-code create that file, then it gives error if apache want to edit this file.

**Error is: The stream of file could not be opened in append mode.**

How I solved this problem daily?

Welll, everyday I'm running the following command to get rid of that above error, I manually set ownership of file

```
sudo chown habib:www-data laravel-2021-03-22.log
```

[image]

What did I want? I wanted to set the ownership in such a way that it will automatically make the owner of the newly created file as habib and the owner group as www-data when the file is created. Plz, tell me whether it's a correct solution or not, and if yes then how to implement that?

Comment: Have you tried giving that access to the folder instead `sudo chown habib:www-data logs` or  ` sudo chown -R habib:www-data logs`

Comment: Yes, already did, the owner of my logs folder is habib and owner group is www-data

Comment: Your second command will update the ownership for existing files. I'm talking about newly created files.

Comment: you can add www-data user to habib group, and add habib to www-data group, also set permission in config/logging.php to 0664

Comment: You can try another route, which is adding the permission for newly created files e.g `permission => 0666` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#configuring-the-single-and-daily-channels

Answer (score 0):

use below command in your app directory to gave access permission on storage directory.
`sudo chmod -R 777 storage`